# how to debug simplescalar sim-fast.c in visual studio 2019?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-debugging, wsl-2

I have made a few change in simplescalar sim-fast.c, but I don't able to debug this change in visual studio 2019.
are there any way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Did VS report some error messages? Could you share related steps with us to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I open Sim-fest.c as a folder in VS and make changes to it, Then in WSL, Mack it, and with slittle-na-sstrix-gcc compile it, then run it. And I never compiled and debugged it with VS.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it seems you are trying to debug an opened file/folder right?

Visual Studio is not supported to build/debug a file/folder, at least it is not possible for a single file. For folders, some may be supported, but need to have some files been included, such as a `.sln` file, a `.vcxproj` file and so on. Instead, Visual Studio supports to build/debug a project/solution.

I'm not familiar with simplescalar, I guess it is not possible to open it as a project/solution in Visual Studio to build and debug though. You can have a try open it as a project, and perhaps consider using other editor tools, if it can't be opened as a project, for example [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).